# gradle build Error in installation

Tags: android, android-studio

I am gettting this error on installing android studio, I don't know what to do next:
    Could not download gradle-core.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.3): 
    No cached version available for offline mode

please help.

Comment: I think your internet is not working properly. Check your internet and try to install fresh android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Untick this box in the settings (File → Settings)

You are offline so gradle can't download the missing files.

[image]